# Google Sheets Script Merge rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to merge two tables by columns and rows

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

**Desired results**

[image]

How do I write a google app script for this work?
Thank you!

Comment: your question is not very clear, what have you done to achieve it ? what do you mean by script?
plus why would you reinvent the wheel since you can already merge tables via the built-in functions of excel/ google sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it's the best solution, but if you want to apply only a single formula then do the following

Table A and Table B should be identical in size, add one additional column in both tables, and match headings in both the tables, similar to your **desired result table.**

You can leave the **"Returned"** column empty in **"Table A"** and **"Sold"** in **"Table B**"

Change your Date format to **"YYYY-MM-DD"**

And then apply the below formula in your summary/final sheet:

```
=QUERY({A!A2:D4;B!A2:D4},"Select Col1,Col2, Sum(Col3), Sum(Col4) group by Col2,Col1 order by Col1,Col2 desc  ")
```

Later on, you can change the date format in your desired result table per your choice.

[image]